# how to retrieve value from map c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have  `map<string, inode_ptr> directories`
I want to retrieve the value associated with a certain key.
so I did this: `inode_ptr i = directories.find("string");`
But it is returning the string key, what should I do?

Comment: `std::map::find` returns an iterator to a `std::pair` `->first` is the key `->second` is value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following approach

```
inode_ptr i = NULL;

auto it = directories.find("string");

if ( it != directories.end() ) i = it->second;
```

Maybe it is even better to write

```
inode_ptr i = {};
```

instead of

```
inode_ptr i = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go:

```
inode_ptr myInode = NULL;    

map<string, inode_ptr>::iterator i = directories.find("string"); 
if ( i != directories.end() )
{
  myInode = i->second;
}
else
{
  cerr << "no 'String' in the map, I should be "
       << "sure to check for null before using myInode" << endl;
}
```

Here is a link to that fine manual referenced in the above comments:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/

Comment: And your code will probably die a horrible death if the key `"string"` doesn't exist.

Comment: It most certainly will.  He didn't ask for a safe way to do it.

Comment: Brilliant! I'll remember that the next time I answer a question ... unless the OP specifies *safe*, it's OK for the solution to work in a limited set of circumstances.

Comment: @AllenKll _'He didn't ask for a safe way'_ That's what's expected as a matter of course from every programmer (including you)! Your _disclaimer_ is pretty lame. How can we check that `find("string")` failed?

Comment: Fine, you shamed me into it.